# I need to use variables and strings to print data

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment where I am given a set of data and I must print it as the assignment shows. The code should also be able to print other strings and get the same layout.

So the issue that I am having is I need to make sure that the data gets printed correctly and they have to printed on the correct line as well. Also like previously stated the code must be able to run other string values as well and format the string similarly.

For example:

```
var phrase = "john q smith, 123 Main Street, Anytown Ohio 45454";
```

I must make it look like this:

```
John Q SMITH (on the first line)
123 Main Street (on the second line)
Anytown, Ohio (on the third line)
45454 (on the fourth line)
```

And using that **same** code switch the var phrase to

```
var phrase = "patrick j.r. Ewing III, 666 KENTUCKY BouRbon LanE, Knots Landing California 95039-1234"
```

And get the output:

```
Patrick J.R. EWING III (this would be on one line)
666 Kentucky Bourbon Lane (this would be on the second line)
Knots Landing, California (this the third line)
95039-1666 (and this on the fourth line)
```

Here is my work:

```
var phrase = "patrick j.r. Ewing III,666 KENTUCKY BouRbon LanE, Knots 
Landing California 95039-1234"; 

var phraseSplit = phrase.split(","); 

var a1 = phraseSplit[0];
var a2 = phraseSplit[1];
var a3 = phraseSplit[2]; 


var a3Split = a3.split(" "); 
var b2 = a3Split[0];
var b3 = a3Split[1]; 
var b4 = a3Split[2]; 
var b5 = a3Split[3];
var b6 = a3Split[4]; 

// line 0

var cD1Split = a1.split (" "); 

    var count1 = a1.indexOf(" ");

    var firstLetter2 = a1.charAt(0); 
    var restofFN2 = a1.charAt(1);
    var upperCaseFirstLetter1 = a1.charAt(0).toUpperCase(); //First Letter 
in Name Capital
    var firstStateWOFL1 = a1.slice(1 , a1.indexOf(" ")); // finding rest 
of 
name 
    var stateWOFL = firstStateWOFL1.toLowerCase(); //makes rest of first 
name lowercase

    output = a1.substring(a1.indexOf(" "),count1);

    output += a1.substring(count1+1).toUpperCase()+" ";

var allTogether = upperCaseFirstLetter1 + firstStateWOFL1 ;

// line 1

function upperCaseFirstLetter(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters(string) {
return string.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (word) {
    return word.charAt(0) + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
});
}

var input = a2;
var desiredOutput1 = 
upperCaseFirstLetter(lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters(input));

//line 2 part a

function upperCaseFirstLetter(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters(string) {
return string.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (word) {
    return word.charAt(0) + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
});
}

var input = b3;
var desiredOutput2 = 
upperCaseFirstLetter(lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters(input));

//line 2 part b

function upperCaseFirstLetter(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters(string) {
return string.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (word) {
    return word.charAt(0) + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
});
}

var input = b4;
var desiredOutput3 = 
upperCaseFirstLetter(lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters(input));



print(allTogether + " " + output + "\n" + desiredOutput1 + "\n" + 
desiredOutput2 + " " + desiredOutput3);
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. There's no question here yet--what *specific* issues are you having?

Comment: Use the `split()` function to split the string at comma characters, then put each part on the desired line.

Comment: If you share your attempt at this, we can help you get it working.

Comment: The issue is that I need the phrase to be printed out in the given way. And that same code must be used to print other sets of data. But I am having trouble doing so. My work can be found here: https://rextester.com/GPSGO51773

Comment: Your work should be found in your question.

Comment: Please edit the relevant portions of your code into the question to preserve your questions long-term value once your link goes dead or the code on that link changes.  Also, some of us cannot reach that link anyway due to corporate firewalls.

Comment: Okay. I edited the portions and included my work into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have

```
var phrase = "john q smith, 123 Main Street, Anytown Ohio 45454";
```

You need

```
John Q SMITH
123 Main Street
Anytown, Ohio 
45454
```

So first, notice how all the input is a string that is split by commas and a space.

```
let substrings = phrase.split(', ');
```

Now that you have 3 substrings

```
[ 'john q smith', '123 Main Street', 'Anytown Ohio 45454' ]
```

Now, I'm assuming you'll need to edit each, so for good sake let's make another subarray.

```
substrings.map(el => {
  return el.split(' ');
})
```

Now you have

```
[
  [ 'john', 'q', 'smith' ],
  [ '123', 'Main', 'Street' ],
  [ 'Anytown', 'Ohio', '45454' ]
]
```

Now your goal is to:

1. Array 1: Capitalize first letter of first name
2. Array 1: Uppercase the rest
3. Array 2: Capitalize first letter of everything after the numbers
4. Array 3: Capitalize all
5. Array 3: Add a comma before the final input (Etc, Etc 12345)
6. Array 3: Put the final element of the 3rd array on a newline

Basically, you can achieve all the above by

```
Using #toUpperCase() and toLowerCase()
Using indexes and iteration 
Using if statements
Using console.log
Using #join() to bring the array back together
Using + for string concatenation
```

Good luck!

EDIT: Attached full answer. 
[image]

All you have to do now is put the answer into a function that takes a phrase, then outputs the correctly formatted information. e.g

```
function addressFormatter(phrase) { }
```

EDIT 2: Full code.

https://repl.it/@TedTran3/EnviousDemandingNanotechnology

So you don't need to rewrite all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201768/discussion-on-answer-by-tedtran2019-i-need-to-use-variables-and-strings-to-print).